# Using machine learning to win an RTS game with unknowns

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, montecarlo

I'm using Python to write a simple board game (based off [generals.io](http://generals.io)) and have the system learn strategy from observing how the user plays; **How can this be formulated as a machine-learning problem?**

## Description

The game is won when one player captures the other's general. Usually, the winning player has a much larger army than the loser so I thought army size could be used to weight the outcome, but it is also possible to win with a much smaller army by using some more complex strategies, so essentially the outcome is a binary win-lose.

Some types of data available to the program are a turn count, the size of the opponents army and a 2-dimensional list, where each element is a dictionary representing a square of the board. Each dictionary holds who owns the square, what type of square it is (starting position, obstacle etc) and what value the square holds (the size of the army on it).

## Current approach

I've looked around an a MCTS seems like it would be a good option, but this is not a turn based game, and the for the most part the other player's positions and moves are unknown (until a conflict occurs).

Comment: This is a cool question but is extremely broad as it currently is: Can you not define what the winning condition(s) is/are in more detail?

Comment: I've added some information on the win conditions, but if you want to get a better feel of the game pop over to [generals.io](http://generals.io) and play the quick tutorial.

Comment: I would love to help but I don't have the time to play in order to figure out how to model the game; your edit has provided more detail but it is still a bit vague-- I mean, what you wrote sounds a lot like chess, which can easily be accomplished without any machine learning involved at all.

Comment: There are a lot of random variables - obstacles on the map, placement of squares that give you an advantage, placement of your starting position and even the dimensions of the board, so I don't know how effective writing a general AI would be. I was also going to use this as an opportunity to dive a bit deeper into ML, I just don't know where to start

Comment: I've been looking at sckit-learn tutorials and have been researching some basic principles of ML, so I want to explore it a bit further. Maybe once I've used machine learning, I could move onto a heuristic approach and see which is most efficient, but for now I'd like to focus on ML

Comment: I've reworded the question to remove the request for a library and have added details of the specific program I have, but it is hard to say what I have already done as I haven't done much. I really just need a starting point, be it a specific process, an algorithm or a library that will help me out.

Comment: Thanks; I'll get back to this in a bit, when I have some more time.

Comment: Cheers - I was just trying to clarify it so it could be reopened

Comment: Thank you for removing the request for a library, but unfortunately this question is still too broad for Stack Overflow. Questions that ask "where do I start" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. See [**Where to Start**](//meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/6367/143094).

Comment: @ScottWeldon there are many examples of questions on SO which have multiple "correct" answers which are not closed. I'm pretty sure OP's asking for an appropriate ML formulation for his scenario and, while there may not be *one* answer, some answers are certainly more appropriate than others: for example, a [linear classifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_classifier) is *not* appropriate here (at least by itself).

Comment: @ScottWeldon That link looks like it's for new programmers and people facing problems they have no idea how to solve. I know I need a ML approach, I know the language and I've given the scenario, I just need the right subsection of ML